# Using SED to convert sensors command output to a loggable entry

Tags: linux, sed

Consider the following `sensor` command output:

```
amdgpu-pci-0100
temp1:        +67.0°C  crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C

amdgpu-pci-0600
temp1:        +59.0°C  crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C

amdgpu-pci-0700
temp1:        +64.0°C  crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C

it8721-isa-0290
Vbat:         +3.43 V
temp1:        +43.0°C  low  = +97.0°C, high = -90.0°C  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +40.0°C  low  = +79.0°C, high =  +2.0°C  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
temp3:       -128.0°C  low  = -128.0°C, high = +69.0°C  sensor = disabled

k10temp-pci-00c3
temp1:        +25.1°C  high = +70.0°C
                       crit = +90.0°C, hyst = +87.0°C

fam15h_power-pci-00c4
power1:       13.04 W  crit =  94.99 W

asus-isa-0000
cpu_fan:        0 RPM
```

I'm trying to turn this into a log entry, like this, where the "temp1" values are placed next to the PCI adapters, and the board (it8721-isa-0290):

```
<Date_Time> amdgpu-pci-0100  -  +67.0°C  |  amdgpu-pci-0600  -  +59.0°C  |  amdgpu-pci-0700  -  +64.0°C  |  it8721-isa-0290  -  +43.0°C
```

I think sed is the correct tool for this, but if it's not please let me know. I have already trimmed some data out using 2 sed commands, but I am not quite sure how to either delete out the rest that I don't need or match on just the stuff I do need. Some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here's what I have so far as far as a command:

```
sensors | sed -e '/Adapter/d' -e '/in/d' -e 's/[)(]//g' -e '/Vbat/d' \
`-e 's/crit.*//' -e 's/low.*//' -e '/temp2/d' -e '/temp3/d' -e '/^k10temp-pci-`00c3$/,$d' \
-e 's/temp.://'
```

Here's the output (just need to add some separators):

```
amdgpu-pci-0100 +68.0°C amdgpu-pci-0600 +60.0°C amdgpu-pci-0700 +65.0°C it8721-isa-0290 +44.0°C
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish what I did?

Comment: Removed some of the sensor output data as I found an easy way to trim a bunch out.

Comment: It's getting crazier, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: sed is the wrong tool for this since sed is only for simple substitutions on individual lines and that is not what you are trying to do. I don't see the correlation between your input and your output. A lot of values from your input are missing. Why? [edit] your question to explain what it is you are trying to do in terms of which input fields map to which output fields and why.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your input. I tried to clear up the question a bit more but I don't know if it helped =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the `sensors` command heavily depends on the configuration file. For example, it is possible to [rename the labels](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/lm_sensors#Example_2._Renaming_Labels) with a configuration similar to the following:

```
chip "as99127f-*"
  label temp1 "Mobo Temp"
  label temp2 "CPU0 Temp"
```

With such configuration the output of `sensors` command will look like this:

```
Mobo Temp:        +35.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst = -128.0°C)
CPU0 Temp:        +47.5°C  (high = +100.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)
```

However, the `sensors` utility provides `-u` switch that prints an easy-to-parse raw data. In raw mode, the chip feature names are printed in standard formats such as `temp1_input`, `temp1_max`, `temp1_crit`, and `temp1_crit_alarm`, e.g.:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:
  temp1_input: 64.000
  temp1_crit: 120.000
temp2:
  temp2_input: 30.000
  temp2_crit: 120.000

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:
  temp1_input: 67.000
  temp1_max: 87.000
  temp1_crit: 105.000
  temp1_crit_alarm: 0.000
Core 0:
  temp2_input: 67.000
  temp2_max: 87.000
  temp2_crit: 105.000
  temp2_crit_alarm: 0.000
  ...
```

The format is still not as easy to parse as it could be (think of JSON, or XML). The chip feature blocks are separated with newlines. Each block starts with the chip name. So you need to remember when the block starts, and print when the block ends (an empty line, or end of file).

It is possible to implement the algorithm in AWK. It is even possible to do this in SED. But I find these tools inconvenient for this case. I would rather use more flexible tool such as Perl (maybe I have just used to Perl more than to AWK).

**Example**

*sensors-temp.pl*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $nl = 0;
my $chip;
my @t;

while (<>) {
  if ($chip eq "" or $nl) {
    ($chip = $_) =~ s/\n*$//;
    @t = ()
  } elsif ($_ =~ /temp\d+_input: ([\d\.]+)/m) {
     push @t, $1;
  }

  $nl = $_ eq "\n";

  # Average chip's temperature
  if ($nl or eof()) {
    my $t; map { $t += $_ } @t;
    printf("%s - %.1f°C\n", $chip, $t / (scalar @t))
  }
}
```

*Usage*

```
sensors -u | perl sensors-temp.pl
```

*Sample Output*

```
acpitz-virtual-0 - 47.5°C
coretemp-isa-0000 - 65.4°C
```

The script calculates average temperature for the `temp\d+_input` entries. You can easily change the script to fit our needs. For example, in order to print a list of all "input" temperatures for a chip, replace the last block in the loop with the following:

```
printf("%s - %s°C\n", $chip, join("|", map { sprintf("%.1f", $_) } @t))
  if $nl or eof();
```

*Sample Output*

```
acpitz-virtual-0 - 67.0|30.0°C
coretemp-isa-0000 - 68.0|67.0|63.0|66.0|61.0°C
```

**P.S.**

The code in the samples prints newlines for each chip for the sake of clarity. Replace the newlines (`\n`) with " | ", or whatever you find suitable for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info about the sensors command. I marked yours as the correct answer. The others should all work too, but driving the formatting directly with sensors is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are more elegant ways to do this but maybe it might help:

```
sensors | egrep -o "\S+-\S+|\+[0-9]+\...C" | egrep "\S+-\S+" -A 1 | sed 's/--/|/g' | head -n -3 | tr '\n' ' '
```

Where the first `grep` only matches strings-like-this and temperature values, the second `grep` again matches strings-like-this and one line after each of them, `sed` converts -- (generated by the second grep) to | , then `head` removes the last 3 strings (this works only in your particular output) and `tr` removes newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You said: "The last one is pretty hard coded, and I don't like it because it's not very flexible." That`s true, but I think this problem is inherent to the process producing your data and not to the tool that is used to generate your desired output.
I came up with this solution. If you are interested in the details of the commands I used, just ask:

```
 sensors | sed -n -e '/^k10temp-pci-00c3$/,$ s/.*//; /^[^ \\\t]\+$/ H;' \
       -e '/^temp1:/ {s/^temp1:[ \\\t]\+\([+-][0-9]*.[0-9]\+°C\).*/\1/; H;}' \
       -e '$ {x; s/^\n//; :start /\n/ {s/\n/ - /; s/\n/ | /; b start;}; s/^\(.*\)/<Date Time> \1/; p;}'
```

Comment: Ok, it's good to know that other solutions look similarly as ugly. I just assumed I was missing some "Eureka" moment with SED that would make it a lot more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you're trying to do but this produces the output you say you want from the input you posted:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[^[:space:]:]+$/ { name = $0 }
name == "k10temp-pci-00c3" { print ts, rec; exit }
$1 == "temp1:" { rec = (rec=="" ? "" : rec "  |  ") name "  -  " $2 }

$ awk -v ts="$(date +'%F %T')" -f tst.awk file
2016-11-26 09:26:35 amdgpu-pci-0100  -  +67.0°C  |  amdgpu-pci-0600  -  +59.0°C  |  amdgpu-pci-0700  -  +64.0°C  |  it8721-isa-0290  -  +43.0°C
```

Is that all you're trying to do - print the first temp1 values for each bock before k10?

Comment: Yes, that is all I was trying to do. Now that I know sensors can have its own formatting, I think it makes more sense to use that to format as much as possible, then clean up a little bit with SED. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
sensors | sed -e '/Adapter/d' -e '/in/d' -e 's/[)(]//g' -e '/Vbat/d' \
`-e 's/crit.*//' -e 's/low.*//' -e '/temp2/d' -e '/temp3/d' -e '/^k10temp-pci-`00c3$/,$d' \
-e 's/temp.://'
```

`sensors` - grab the raw output

`'/Adapter/d'` - Remove lines containing "Adapter"

`'/in/d'` - Remove lines containing "in"

`'s/[)(]//g'` - Remove Parenthesis

`'/Vbat/d'` - Remove lines containing "Vbat"

`'s/crit.*//'` - Remove everything after "crit" on a line

`'s/low.*//'` - Remove everything after "low" on a line

`'/temp2/d'` - Remove lines containing "temp2"

`'/temp3/d'` - Remove lines containing "temp3"

`'/^k10temp-pci-00c3$/,$d'` - Remove everything after "k10temp-pci-`00c3"

The last one is pretty hard coded, and I don't like it because it's not very flexible.